# Remove Vertical Scroll in Page Viewer web part viewing a Folder

Tags: iframe, page-viewer-web-part

A Page Viewer web part was added to a page. The Page Viewer points to a SharePoint library folder. The folder and its contents are viewed in the IFRAME, but the box has a vertical scroll. I've tried everything to hide, including adding a "overflow:hidden;" css mod, didn't work. Ideas?
edit: meant to say "hide the vertical scroll"

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar comes from within the iframe and is therefore inaccessible by CSS on the hosting page.
You can, however, add some JavaScript to the page that is shown in the iframe, that checks the value of a custom parameter in the querystring and adds your *overflow:hidden* accordingly.

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); 
if(JSRequest.QueryString["scrollbars"] == "false"){
    ... remove scrollbars
}
```

In your iframe configuration you pass the scrollbars parameter with value false to the page.

For example:

```
https://.../AllItems.aspx?scrollbars=false
```